# Laws regarding excessive conversation while dating

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, marriage, speech-talking, shidduchim-dating

In speaking with a friend regarding conversation between men and women who are dating, this is what they said:

> So I asked someone who knows about these things and she said that it originates from the gemara, and is in the shulchan aruch, that a couple should not speak too often; there are certain rules to that, and the [last Lubavitcher] rebbe said that a couple shouldn't talk too often. There are people who adopted seeing each other once a week in addition to speaking on the phone once a week. That is a common practice but not everyone talks so little – some talk more often – but there are guidelines to it.

The only source I could find for this was Mishna, Pirkei Avot 1:5, and that is more general. I've looked superficially in Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEezer; and Mishneh Torah, Issurei Biah. I can find nothing concrete.

Please provide specific sources for such an idea, if it indeed comes from traditional Torah sources.

Comment: Are you talking about when engaged, before the wedding, or while dating to decide if they want to marry each other?

Comment: Sources about either circumstance would be wonderful. I'm more interested in the rules while dating to decide regarding marriage.

Comment: The comment from the Lubavitcher Rebbe is talking about during the engagement period, not before hand, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no such source from a time when there was no dating, so you need to look only in the past 50 years of Halacha.

The one known source is from the Gemora (קידושין מא א)

> אסור לאדם שיקדש את האשה עד שיראנה שמא יראה בה דבר מגונה ותתגנה עליו

And now, one should check perhaps also by talking.

Answer (score 1):

Even the mishnah in pirkei avos is not interpreted by many achronim as the simple understanding. 
For example the Maharal explains that the mishnahs meaning is that a man should not learn torah with a woman. (see his peirush on this mishnah in full) but not having to do with having a conversation.

Also a different version in avos derebi natan gives a slightly different approach. Basically saying, to limit the scope of conversation to things that wont cause issues. 
אבות דרבי נתן, פרק שביעי, משנה ג

דבר אחר: אל תרבה שיחה עם האשה כיצד? בזמן שאדם בא לבית המדרש ולא היו נוהגין בו כבוד, או שערער עם חברו, אל ילך ויאמר לאשתו: כך וכך ערערתי עם חברי, כך וכך אמר לי, כך וכך אמרתי לו, מפני שבוזה את עצמו ובוזה את אשתו ובוזה את חברו, ואשתו שהיתה נוהגת בו כבוד עומדת ומשחקת עליו. כיון ששמע חברו אמר: אוי לי, דברים שבינו לביני הלך ושׂחן לאשתו. ונמצא אותו האיש בוזה את עצמו ואת אשתו ואת חברו.
אבות דרבי נתן, פרק שביעי, משנה ג

The Chazon Ish writes that Rizui - time that she needs, certainly does not go into this category (and give a blanket heter for shanah rishonah).
It is attributed to Rav Wolbe that nowadays shana Rishona is 10 years. 
I also heard in the name of a gadol from the last generation, that tarbe, means whatever she needs is appropriate, but if you need more light talk, that is excessive.

Here is a gemara that does support the idea of not having conversation with ones wife. 
אמר רב: אפילו שיחה יתירה שבין איש לאשתו מגידים לו לאדם בשעת מיתה. איני? [האומנם?! והרי] והא רב כהנא הוה גני תותי פורייה דרב [רב כהנא התחבא תחת מיטתו של רב, רבו] ושמעיה דסח וצחק ועשה צרכיו [ושמע את רב משוחח (עם אשתו) וצוחק בשעת האקט המיני] אמר: דמי פומיה דרב כמאן דלא טעים ליה תבשילא [נשמע פיו של רב כאדם שמעולם לא טעם תבשיל, כלומר תאב מאוד]. אמר ליה [רב לכהנא]: כהנא פוק לאו אורח ארעא! [כהנא צא! זוהי לא דרך ארץ!] לא קשיא [אין סתירה בין דברי רב להתנהגותו עם אשתו]: כאן דצריך לרצויה, הא דלא צריך לרצויה [כאן, שהיה צריך לרצות אותה, ושם (בדבריו לעיל) כשאין צורך לרצותה].
תלמוד בבלי, מסכת חגיגה, דף ה, עמוד ב